# Not getting the id attribute value in this code

Tags: jquery

I'm getting only id attribute value in first row only but want to get attribute values in other dynamically created rows.On click in table row input tag should be display
Please help me in finding the solution.

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var id = parseInt($('#main tbody tr:last').attr('id')) + 1;
        $('#main > tbody:last').append("<tr class=\"edit_tr\" id=\"" + id + "\" ><td>" + id + "</td><td><span id=\"parti_" + id + "\" class=\"text\" ></span><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"parti_input_" + id + "\" /></td><td><span id=\"qty_" + id + "\" class=\"text\"></span><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"qty_input_" + id + "\" /></td><td><span id=\"amountrs_" + id + "\" class=\"text\"></span><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"amountrs_input_" + id + "\" /></td><td><span id=\"amountp_" + id + "\" class=\"text\"></span><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox\" id=\"amountp_input_" + id + "\" /></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
    });
    $('#del').click(function () {
        $('#main tbody tr:last').remove();
    });
    $(".edit_tr").click(function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#parti_" + ID).hide();
        $("#qty_" + ID).hide();
        $("#amountrs_" + ID).hide();
        $("#amountp_" + ID).hide();
        $("#parti_input_" + ID).show();
        $("#qty_input_" + ID).show();
        $("#amountrs_input_" + ID).show();
        $("#amountp_input_" + ID).show();
    }).change(function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var first = $("#first_input_" + ID).val();
        var last = $("#last_input_" + ID).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&firstname=' + first + '&lastname=' + last;
        $("#first_" + ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image
    });
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function () {
        return false
    });
    // Outside click action
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        $(".editbox").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="edit_tr" id="1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><span id="parti_1" class="text"></span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox part" id="parti_input_1" />
        </td>
        <td><span id="qty_1" class="text"></span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" id="qty_input_1" />
        </td>
        <td><span id="amountrs_1" class="text"></span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" id="amountrs_input_1" />
        </td>
        <td><span id="amountp_1" class="text" /></span>
            <input type="text" class="editbox" id="amountp_input_1" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what do you want exactly? I See only this http://jsfiddle.net/rq2ut/2/

Comment: check jquery on method..

Comment: `$('document').ready` should be `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `#main` or `<table>` in your markup, so I added myself.

If you want to target `tbody` like this `#main > tbody` then #`main` must be inside the `<table>` tag. I just removed it in my example. Was this what you were looking for?

Check here

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPQsq/)**

I also corrected the extra `'` in the ready function, should be `$(document)`. Added also a button just for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation to attach event listeners to dynamically created elements. Depending on which version of jQuery you're using, you'll use `.on`, `.delegate` or `.live`.

```
$("body")
    .on('click', ".edit_tr", function () {
        ...
    })
    .on('change', ".edit_tr", function () {
        ...
    });
```